# csh bindkey what is "\346"

Tags: bash, shell, bind, csh

It looks like I cannot use Ctrl+right_arrow to forward word on my c shell. After some effort I found out that the all the key bindings can be found with `bindkey` command and I get these:

```
"\306"         ->  forward-word
"\316"         ->  history-search-forward
"\346"         ->  forward-word
"\356"         ->  history-search-forward
"^[[C"         -> forward-char
"^[OC"         -> forward-char
"^[F"          -> forward-word
```

Any idea what these all mean? It would be AWESOME if you can point me to where I can learn what these characters mean :)

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that `\3xx` is Meta+`\0xx`, so `\346` is Meta-F.

Comment: and you guess is based on what?

Comment: Based on the assumption that the default bindings are Emacs-like, and 046 is ASCII F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the `csh` man page, "\nnn" is the ASCII character corresponding to the *octal* number `nnn`. The octal (base-8) number in decimal is 198. Barmer is correct, as "F" (ASCII 046, decimal 70) becomes 306 when you set the high bit.

Comment: what about '[' or '[['?

Comment: '^[' is Control-[, or ESC. The first two aren't meant to be typed literally; various non-printable keys (arrow keys, HOME, END, function keys, etc) generate escape sequences. The last one is ESC-F, which is simply the escape key followed by F.